# Integrating Tflite in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, random-forest, tflite

I am new to Flutter. I want to integrate a Random Forest model that have age, heart beat, temperature, and oxygen saturation as input to diagnose a disease (output either 0 or 1). I have made the random_forest.tflite file using python. However, I couldn't integrate that file with flutter. I tried to use tflite and tflite_flutter. Both gave me errors. If you know any other way to integrate the model in flutter, I'd like to know it.

That is the class I made with flutter using the guide in that link: https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter

```
class _MachineLearningState extends State<MachineLearning> {
  var predValue = "";
  late Interpreter interpreter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    predValue = "click predict button";

    initInterpreter();
  }

  Future<void> initInterpreter() async {
    interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/random_forest.tflite');
  }

  Future<void> predData() async {
    List<List<double>> input = [
      [953.0, 1075.0, 1695.0, 5340.0]
    ];
    List<List<int>> output = List.filled(1, 0).reshape([1, 1]) as List<List<int>>;
    
    interpreter.run(input, output);

    setState(() {
      predValue = output[0][0].toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              "change the input values in code to get the prediction",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: predData,
              child: const Text(
                "predict",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
            Text(
              "Predicted value :  $predValue ",
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 23),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the previous code, the line `interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/random_forest.tflite');` doesn't run correctly it gives me that error `exception = {StateError} Bad state: failed precondition`

_stackTrace:

```
#0      checkState (package:quiver/check.dart:74:5)
#1      Interpreter.allocateTensors (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:156:5)
#2      new Interpreter._ (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:49:5)
#3      new Interpreter._create (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:60:24)
#4      new Interpreter.fromBuffer (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:109:37)
#5      Interpreter.fromAsset (package:tflite_flutter/src/interpreter.dart:126:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      _MachineLearningState.initInterpreter (package:dvt_predictor/main.dart:307:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I have already put the following in the pubspec.ymal (and added all the packages I used):

```
flutter:
    assets:
        - assets/random_forest.tflite
```